# Indexing of string values in JSONB nested arrays in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing, full-text-search, jsonb

I have a complex object with JSONB (PostgreSQL 12), that has nested arrays in nested arrays and so on. I search for all invoices, that contains specific criteria.

```
create table invoice:
invoice_number primary key text not null,
parts: jsonb,
...
```

Object:

```
"parts": [
 { 
  "groups": [
    {
    "categories": [
       {
         "items": [
            {
              ...
              "articleName": "article1",
              "articleSize": "M",
            },
            {
              ...
              "articleName": "article2"
              "articleSize": "XXL",
            }
         ]
       }
     ] 
    }
  ] 
 },
 {
  "groups": [
     ...
  ] 
 },
]
```

I've a build a native query to search for items with a specific articleName:

```
select * from invoice i, 
    jsonb_array_elements(i.invoice_parts) parts, 
    jsonb_array_elements(parts -> 'groups') groups, 
    jsonb_array_elements(groups -> 'categories') categories, 
    jsonb_array_elements(categories -> 'items') items 
where items ->> 'articleName' like '%name%' and items ->> 'articleSize' = 'XXL';
```

I assume i could improve search speed with indexing. I've read about Trigram indexes. Would it be the best type of indexing for my case? If yes -> how to build it for such complex object.

Thanks in regards for any advices.

Comment: If you know the structure of your data, don't use an unstructured type like JSON. You're just making life complicated for yourself.

Comment: You are unnesting multiple arrays, then you have a WHERE condition on the result of _that_. No index is going to help here. The best solution is to properly normalize the data model.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Our structure is normalized. But when the invoice is created, we finalize it. Our goal is to have invoice for years final, independent from other table changes, like addresses / names etc.

So if there is no any other recommendation, i ll think more about to inject this structure into ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option that *might* speed up this, is to create a GIN index on the `parts` column and use a JSON path operator:

```
select *
from invoice
where parts @? '$.parts[*].groups[*].categories[*].items[*] ? (@.articleName like_regex "name" && @.articleSize == "XXL")'
```

But I doubt this is going to be fast enough, even if that uses the index.

Comment: will make a complex search over ElasticSearch. Thanks for thoughts sharing.